# create multiple cache objects using a factory

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kmWjYLTdSau3d8T114Bz?p=preview) I have a factory that wraps Angular's `$cacheFactory`. The controller uses the factory to create two independent caches, however I get the following error: `cacheManager is not a function`. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtl">
  cache1 : {{cache1 | json}}
  <br/>
  cache2 : {{cache2 | json}}
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);    
app.controller('myCtl', function ($scope,cacheManager) {

    var cache1 = new cacheManager();
    var cache2 = new cacheManager();

    cache1.create("cache1");
    cache2.create("cache2");

    cache1.add("key1", "value1");
    cache2.add("key2", "value2");
})

.factory('cacheManager',function($cacheFactory){

    var factory = {};
    var cache = null;

    factory.create = function(cacheId){  
        cache = $cacheFactory(cacheId); 
        return cache;
    };

    factory.add = function(key,value){
        if (!cache)
            return;
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    factory.get = function(key){
        if (!cache)
            return;
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    return factory;

});
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800909/angularjs-return-new-factory-instance

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that did the trick, the factory needs to return a function to allow the controller do a new. Also, the methods need to be defined with the `prototype` keyword:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('myCtl', function ($scope,cacheManager) {

    var cache1 = new cacheManager();
    var cache2 = new cacheManager();

    cache1.create("cache1");
    cache2.create("cache2");

    cache1.add("key1", "value1");
    cache2.add("key2", "value2");

    alert(cache1.get("key1"));


})

.factory('cacheManager',function($cacheFactory){

    var factory = function() { };

    factory.cache = null;

    factory.prototype.create = function(cacheId){  
        cache = $cacheFactory(cacheId); 
        return cache;
    };

    factory.prototype.add = function(key,value){
        if (!cache)
            return;
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    factory.prototype.get = function(key){
        if (!cache)
            return;
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    return factory;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

cacheManager is a Object and its not a function()

```
        cacheManager.create("cache1");
        cacheManager.create("cache2");

        cacheManager.add("key1", "value1");
        cacheManager.add("key2", "value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not create multiple instances of cacheManager instead you should create multiple cache objects and add multiple key/value to the different cache objects.

```
var cache1 = cacheManager.create("cache1");
    var cache2 = cacheManager.create("cache2");
```

cache1.add("key1", "value1");
    cache2.add("key2", "value2");

Comment: you can add multiple key/value on cache1 as well as cache2.
like cache1.add('key11','11');cache1.add('key22','22');cache1.add('key33','33');