# angular factory. how to create new instances of the factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-factory

I am trying to create new instances of a factory but, all the time it prints the last instance (because of its singleton).
How can I achieve new instance every time I create with the `new` keyword?
I created example of what I am trying to achieve in jsfiddle.net
Thanks.

```
angular.module('mainModule', []);

  Crud.$inject = ['$http'];

    function Crud($http) {

        function CrudFactory(crudDTO) {
            var vm = CrudFactory;
                        vm.x = 1;
            vm.addX = addX;
            vm.getX = getX;
            vm.print = print;

            function addX(){
                vm.x +=1;
            }
            function getX(){

                return vm.x;
            }
            function print(){
                console.log(crudDTO.entity);
            }

            return vm;
        }

        return CrudFactory;
    }

    angular
        .module('mainModule')
        .factory('Crud', Crud);


    angular.module('mainModule').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,Crud){
    var a = new Crud({entity:"test1"});
    var b = new Crud({entity:"test2"});
    //a.addX();
    //$scope.a =b.getX();
    a.print();
    b.print();
    a.print();
});
```

Comment: Change vm from CrudFactory to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-Singleton Services in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626075/non-singleton-services-in-angular)

Comment: vm is supposed to be used in controllers; does not make any sense to me to use it in factories (we bind view/tpl and model in controllers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing it wrongly. You have to reference the instance of the called function with `this` rather than with the function name again.

Instead

```
var vm = CrudFactory;
```

change

```
var vm = this;
```

**Working Demo**:

http://jsfiddle.net/haqL7m5q/2/

Comment: how its possible to create new instance if the factory is singleton?

Comment: You can check this link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626075/non-singleton-services-in-angular ? Check the fiddle to see how we can use objects to trigger the functions in factory