# Basic behaviour and structure of an angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, architecture, frameworks

I am trying to introduce myself into angularjs.

Although i have worked through the tutorial and watched the basic building videos, i am still struggling with the behaviour and architecture of a more-or-less large scale application.

My application has a menubar that includes an add-button. If the user clicks the button, i want a dialog to pop-up. That dialog is not part of the menu:

```
<!-- The menu -->
<header class="mod modHeader" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
  <div class="modHeader__addProject" ng-click="openAddDialog()">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-2x"></i>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- the dialog -->
<div class="modNewProject" ng-show="properties.AddDialogVisibility" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <!-- content stripped out -->
</div>
```

My intention was to create a `properties` object inside the scope of my `HeaderCtrl` controller, then change a boolean value on click of the said button.

```
// HeaderCtrl
function HeaderCtrl($scope){
  $scope.properties = {
    "AddDialogVisibility": false
  };

  $scope.openAddDialog = function () {
    $scope.properties.AddDialogVisibility = true;
  };

}
```

Now, there are multiple issues and questions:

- I have to apply HeaderCtrl to my dialog in order to get access to the properties object. This is nasty to me, HeaderCtrl should control only my header module, shouldn't it?
- The dialog won't show up on click. I found out that this is because the property gets checked only once, on page load, and that i would have to use a function. What is a proper way to achieve my goal?

**Conclusion:**

I would say that i can summarize my question to:
I use a Controller for each section of my page. How do they communicate?

Comment: There's no AngularJS tag because this is programmers.SE, not StackOverflow. I've flagged this question for migration to that community.

Comment: Additionally - your issue is that you're using two instances of the same controller, meaning that they have two different scopes. They don't communicate. I would recommend using a single ng-controller to wrap both your header and dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code you provided, two HeaderCtrls will be created.  Each use of `ng-controller` will create a controller.

To share data in Angular, use a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services).  Inject that service where needed – into controllers, directives, etc.

When designing an Angular app, try to think in terms of models (which are often contained in services, and those services then [expose model APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607874/where-should-model-state-be-stored-in-angular-js#comment23896198_16607874) to the rest of the application) and views.  A controller is just the glue that allows us to project the relevant parts of our models into a view.

Dialogs are a special/unique case, since [they don't take up a specific place in the rest of the application](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/about-those-directives.html?showComment=1357164846776).  Listen to [a few minutes of Misko](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=28m30s) regarding this subject.
I would also recommend looking at how the Angular-UI team implemented dialogs: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#dialog

Comment: I looked up that service stuff and found that there are services, factories and providers. I understand that they differ from each other in functionality and that services may be the easiest to use. But how do i decide which one to choose?

Comment: @Sprottenwels, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provide-vs-factory

Comment: Thank you again, but may i ask one last question? How would you scale that service? One large $objects that serves data application wide, simply enough?

Comment: @Sprottenwels, I'm not sure I understand your question.  What do you need to scale?  A service/factory/provider can be injected wherever you need it (e.g., into multiple controllers, other services, multiple directives, etc.).  A service/factory/provider is a singleton.  Your singleton can contain a collection of things, or you can have one singleton per collection item.

Answer (score 0):

angular structure

```
app-> 

    assets->
           css -> all css file
           js  -> all js file

    partials-> all html files
    vender -> third party file (like angular.js , jquery.js)

      router.js
      services.js
      filter.js
      directives.js
      controllers.js

      index.html
```