# When to use nested controllers instead of services in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, anti-patterns, god-object

I just started to use AngularJS, so I'm not an expert.

I have a div that represent the right area of my html view. In that div I have a controller, i.e.

```
<div class="rightContainer" ng-controller="rightContainerCtrl">...</div>
```

Inside that div I have a table, a search region, etc. Each region inside that div has its own controllers, it looks like this:

```
<div class="rightContainer" ng-controller="rightContainerCtrl">
...
   <div class="search" ng-controller="searchCtrl">...</div>
...
   <div class="table" ng-controller="tableCtrl">...</div>

 </div>
```

the search region for example has its own controller and it is a child of rightContainerCtrl because it needs to alter some content in the parent (rightContainerCtrl), but the rightContainer div is growing and now it's big, and contain several nested controllers.

I think that using this nested controllers it's bad in this context because all the nested controllers share the parent scope, and not all controllers needs to access all the parent scope variables, also all the controllers are "prisoners" of the rightContainerCtrl, so they are highly coupled with their parent controller.

It looks like a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) anti-pattern (God controller in this case), so I think that instead of using nested controllers I can refactor my code to eliminate the rightContainerCtrl controller and use a service instead (like in a [facade design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)), that service then will be used by the controllers instead of sharing scope variables.

but since I'm not an AngularJs expert I'm not sure if I'm right or if it's better to leave this parent controller, maybe I'm missing something, so my question is

When is better to use nested controllers (nested scopes) and when it's better to use services instead in angularjs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Controller/scope hierarchy should not dictate how data/models are shared in an application.  When you think of data sharing in Angular, think dependency injection.

In the video that is referenced in @shaunhusain's answser, Misko states that scope should *refer* to the model, not be the model -- so don't model/put your data into scopes.  Your models/data should normally be in a service.

When writing an Angular app, first think about your models.  Put them in [services with APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607874/where-should-model-state-be-stored-in-angular-js#comment23896198_16607874) to get/edit/manipulate the models.  Then design your views.  Each view should project/use/manipulate some subset of your models.  Define a controller for each view that simply glues the needed subset of the models to the view.  Make your controllers as thin as possible.

(Naming a controller `rightContainerCtrl` is also not recommended.  The controller should not know about presentation/layout.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact the controllers should not know about presentation, so in that sense, just because the view needs a div hierarchy, it doesn't mean that the controllers needs to be nested because they should be decoupled/independent of the views.

Comment: Also if you have a controller and a set of child controllers, it's probably that you are using the parent controller scope as the model, and that's a bad practice, in that case a service is needed, not a parent controller.

Answer (score 7):

This is 100% judgement call, and should be based on a couple of points.

Using events creates extremely loosely coupled components, they literally do not need to be aware of one another, if you have a situation where some parent controller would alleviate the need to communicate between a bunch of controllers (via services) then it is probably a better solution.

However if you're okay with the controllers each depending on the service (not really a problem) then you could just use the service as a means of communicating changes between the controllers.  I've seen tons of arguments against the singleton (of which the service is a flavor, an injected singleton, but singleton nonetheless) I find these arguments to mostly be moot and generally lack a truly elegant and concise solution.  If an argument spouts on and on about how when you go from A - D you don't want to take road B but they never seem to offer road C I don't really see the point.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=30m34s

I couldn't find the exact point in the video, but somewhere at the end here he discusses the usage of controllers vs services (he also reviews bi-directional data binding which will stop you from needing to pollute the global scope so to speak).

Comment: Thanks for share that video, I watched it and now I have a better knowledge about AngularJs. Mark Rajcok exposed a good point in their answer, and also the video explain it. You should use services for your model, and your model needs to be decoupled from the controllers and scopes, so in my example, that rightContainerCtrl it's the model because several nested controllers are using the variables in that scope, but this is a bad practice, it should be a service instead.

Comment: @MiguelA.Carrasco Yup glad you got something out of the video too I've recommended it a lot on here recently since it seems to cover a lot of the common missteps.  I +1ed Mark's answer as well he explained it well and has a lot of other very good answers.

Comment: Writing events to communicate between controllers is definitly a pain. Id much rather use nested scopes for that. Or services.