# Angular json data in service across controllers

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, service, controller

Hey guys i'm new to angular and am not very proficient with javascript.  This setup pulls in the json data fine, however when I make changes to some of the properties in the object, they reset when I change views and the controller is reloaded.  Any help or guidance on how to approach this would be appreciated.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Quiz) {
    $scope.quiz = {};

    Quiz.getQuestions(function(data) {
      $scope.quiz = data;
    });
});

app.service('Quiz', function($http) {
  this.getQuestions = function(callback) {
    $http.get('questions/questions.json').success(function(data) {
      if (callback) {callback(data);}
      return data;
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Example of how to use a service to share/persist data across controllers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112608/angularjs-where-to-put-model-data-and-behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `$http` get request get repeated on subsequent calls to `getQuestions()` overwriting the object?  If so, perhaps

```
app.service('Quiz', function($http) {
  var _data;
  this.getQuestions = function(callback) {
    if (_data) {
       callback(_data); 
    }
    $http.get('questions/questions.json').success(function(data) {
      _data = data;
      if (callback) {callback(data);}
      return data;
    });
  };
});
```