# angularjs use the same service as model with different data

Tags: oop, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm creating a `factory` `service` which provides me couple function like

```
var myApp = angular.module('panelServices', ['ngResource']);

myApp.factory('myService', [...]{ 
  function myService(){
    this.list = [];
  }

  myService.prototype.method1: fn() {} ,
  ...
  myService.prototype.methodn: fn() {},

  return myService;
});
```

The I Inject `myService` via **DI** into my `controllers` and use `new myService()` to instanciate a new instance of `myService`.

I did not find another way to do this, I was thinking of "copying" the `service` into e.g.: `anotherService` (based on the fact that `service` are `singletons`). 
My goal is to have a `service` to use for different `models` (they do not share data, only methods)-

Please tell me if I did not explain well, thanks in advance.

Comment: inject the model in the service may be ...

Comment: do you want multiple instance of your service ?

Comment: practically , yes. I think it is.

Comment: Services operate on models, they shouldn't own it. Maybe you overthink you design. When you call `new` then you essentially don't use automatic dependency injection. So why bother with angular services at all then? If you want to "copy" the service then define `myService` outside the factory and define one service factory for each model.

Comment: @zeroflagL I could agree, but if not in the `controller`, not in a `service`, where do I have to store my model? I think that putting it into a service, insted of putting it symply into the `scope` gives me more separation. Am I thinking it wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112608/angularjs-where-to-put-model-data-and-behaviour

Comment: First of all keep in mind that there is no absolute truth :) Second, the accepted answer to that question is about **shared** data, the opposite of what you want. And it doesn't really cover the question, IMHO. I find the answer with the second highest rating much more appropriate. And as for where the model is stored: An angular controller exposes the model to the view through the scope. That's what a controller is there for in the first place. You would use a service to retrieve or manipulate the model. That said, if you are ok with your solution then just use it.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple instance of service you can use [$injector.instantiate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector#instantiate)

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($injector){ 
  function myService(){
    this.list = [];
  }

  myService.prototype.method1: fn() {} ,
  ...
  myService.prototype.methodn: fn() {},

  return function() {
     return $injector.instantiate(myService);
  };
});
```

And then in controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', function(myService){ 
      var service = new myService();
//other code
});
```

in another controller

```
myApp.controller('anotherController', function(myService){ 
   var service = new myService();
   //other code
});
```

`new myService()` it always give you new instance. See this [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/90SLzLDQOisfQyoa603o?p=preview)

Comment: the factory looks great. But why did you pass a string to the controller? And why are you using new in the Controller? could you explain this? thx

Comment: Your factory returns an object. so how is `new myService()` supposed to work? Apart from that it's exactly what the OP does now.

Comment: Updated my answer and added a demo